# building default cocos2d-x project on windows 8 metro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to run the default app included included in cocos2d-x for win8 metro. It compiles fine but as soon as it starts to run it breaks with this exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0100A2CA in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

I can't seem to find where this error is coming from and how to fix it. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when using the source at http://cocos2d-x.googlecode.com/files/cocos2d-x0.11.0-win8-0.9.1.zip

what solved it for me is to get the source from github at https://github.com/cocos2d-x/cocos2dx-win8